# How to subscribe to the Observable merged with another Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

**UPDATE:**

Seems I imported Observable from the wrong place... Thats so confusing, because I had this statement `import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromevent';`...

So I changed from:
`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';`
To:
`import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`

And now get different error:

> ERROR TypeError: Invalid event target

End of Update

---

```
export class AppComponent { 

  @ViewChild('b') button;

  posts: any[];
  clickStream$: Observable<any>;

    constructor(http: Http){  
       this.clickStream$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.button, 'click').mergeMap(
         () => {
           var randomOffset = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
           return http.get('https://api.github.com/users?since=' + randomOffset);
         });
    }  

    ngOnInit() {
      this.clickStream$.subscribe(res => { this.posts = res.json()});
    }
}
```

Here I get a stream of button clicks, then I want it to merge to other observable from the `get` method, but with random number at the end of url. So my final goal is to render different list of API users every time button is clicked.

HTML:

```
<button>Click</button>

<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
{{ post.login }}
</div>
```

Console error:

> ERROR TypeError:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_rxjs_observable**.Observable.fromEvent is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completally sure about everything I done, but seems made it working with:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { initializeApp, database } from 'firebase';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent { 

  @ViewChild('b') button: ElementRef;

  posts: any[];
  clickStream$: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private http: Http){  
    }  

    ngOnInit() {
       this.clickStream$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click').mergeMap(
         () => {
           var randomOffset = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
           return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users?since=' + randomOffset);
         });

      this.clickStream$.subscribe(res => { this.posts = res.json()});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
```

Comment: sorry, seems you fixed your problem)